# Show all setError messages in Android

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

```
if (!validateEmail(email) || (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))) {
        emailwrapper.setError("Invalid email");
    } else {
        emailwrapper.setError(null);
    }

    if (password.length() < 6 || (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))) {
        passwordwrapper.setError("Password must have at least 6 characters");
        return;

    } else {
        passwordwrapper.setError(null);
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MoreInfo.class));
```

How would I make it so that both error messages display if the two Text Input Layouts are left blank and make sure that the user cannot proceed to the MoreInfo class with only the password filled in correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function, which returns a boolean value and depending on that value proceed accordingly:

```
private boolean areAllFieldsValid() {
    boolean returnValue = true;
    if (!validateEmail(email) || (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))) {
        emailwrapper.setError("Invalid email");
        returnValue = false;
    } else {
        emailwrapper.setError(null);
    }

    if (password.length() < 6 || (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))) {
        passwordwrapper.setError("Password must have at least 6 characters");
        returnValue = false;
    } else {
        passwordwrapper.setError(null);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Now Check this condition using:

```
if(areAllFieldsValid()){
    startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MoreInfo.class));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean variable based on that validate your conditions and then navigate. Try below sample

```
 boolean valid = true;

    if (!validateEmail(email) || (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))) {
            valid = false;
            emailwrapper.setError("Invalid email");
        } else {
            valid = true;
            emailwrapper.setError(null);
        }

        if (password.length() < 6 || (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))) {
             valid = false;
            passwordwrapper.setError("Password must have at least 6 characters");

        } else {
             valid = true;
            passwordwrapper.setError(null);
        }

        if(valid)
          startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MoreInfo.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create method Boolean to check

```
       if(isValid()){
                startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MoreInfo.class));
            }
```

Boolean Mehtod

```
    private boolean isValid() {
    if (!validateEmail(email) || (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))) {
    emailwrapper.setError("Invalid email");
    return false;
    } else {
    emailwrapper.setError(null);
    emailwapper.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    if (password.length() < 6 || (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))) {
    passwordwrapper.setError("Password must have at least 6 characters");
    return false;

    } else {
    passwordwrapper.setError(null);
    passwordwapper.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    retun true;
    }
```